# vhdl assign unconstraint std_logic_vector - lsb to msb or msb downto lsb

Tags: vhdl

i'd like to assign a std_logic_vector without giving the bounds. Like this:

```
constant xy: std_logic_vector := "100111";
```

when i want to access single bits like:

```
xy(0), xy(1)...xy(5)
```

i get

```
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1
```

This is the same, as when i assign the vector like 
*std_logic_vector(0 to 5)*.

Is this behaviour standardized, that assigning a unconstrained vector is interpreted like *std_logic_vector(0 to x)* and not like *std_logic_vector(x downto 0)*, or is this depending on the implementation?

I'm using ghdl right now, but want to use vivado for synthesis.

Comment: It's semantically defined in VHDL. IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.4.2.5 Object declarations para 2 b), there is no implicit subtype conversion here without a constraint. 14.4.2.4 Subtype declarations *...The elaboration of a subtype indication creates a subtype. If the subtype does not include a constraint, then the subtype is the same as that denoted by the type mark....* The type mark here std_logic_vector, the index type subtype natural (range 0 to INTEGER'HIGH).  16.2.3 Predefined attributes of arrays take their values from the elaborated array object whose elements  are left to right ordered.

Comment: You could also have determined ghdl and vivado synthesis have identical semantics here by experimentation.

Comment: Yes, i could. But i was scared, that maybe vivado or ghdl will change this behaviour in future versions. But when it's mentioned in the standard, it's ok.

Comment: A little research goes a long way.

Comment: @user1155120 I really don't understand why you do not makes comments like these into answers. Also, yes he *could* find this result by experimentation, but that would not tell him what the standard actually says. Since the standard is not a public document, it seems unfair to assert that the asker could have found this out definitively for himself.

Comment: Note the accepted answer by EML contains no authoritative reference discounting the value to the OP of what the standard relates, leaving open anecdotal comments and experimentation (or do you think EML didn't analyze, elaborate and simulate his example?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, yes, standardised. When you declare an object of an unconstrained array type you need to supply a constraint to specify the index bounds (so that the compiler can allocate the required memory, and so on). There are several different ways to do this, most of which require you to explicitly specify the array limits and direction.

However, there's an exception for constants (only): the constraint can be inferred from the expression used to initialise the constant. If you initialise from a string literal or an aggregate with positional association (`A` and `B` below) then the index value of the first/left element is taken from the leftmost element of the type in the range declaration, and the direction is taken from the direction of that type. For `std_logic_vector`, the declarations are:

```
SUBTYPE NATURAL is integer range 0 to integer'high;
...
TYPE std_logic_vector IS ARRAY ( NATURAL RANGE <>) OF std_logic;
```

`NATURAL` is ascending, with leftmost index 0, so your `xy` is the same. OTOH, if the initialiser is an aggregate with named association (`C` below) then the index range of the constant is simply taken from the aggregate. The code below should show A and B as 111001, and C as 100111.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity TOP is
end entity TOP;

architecture A of TOP is
begin
  process
    constant A : std_logic_vector := "100111";
    constant B : std_logic_vector := ('1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1');
    constant C : std_logic_vector := 
      (5 => '1', 4 => '0', 3 => '0', 2 => '1', 1 => '1', 0 => '1');
  begin
    report "A is " &
      std_logic'image(A(5)) & std_logic'image(A(4)) & std_logic'image(A(3)) &
      std_logic'image(A(2)) & std_logic'image(A(1)) & std_logic'image(A(0));
    report "B is " &
      std_logic'image(B(5)) & std_logic'image(B(4)) & std_logic'image(B(3)) &
      std_logic'image(B(2)) & std_logic'image(B(1)) & std_logic'image(B(0));
    report "C is " &
      std_logic'image(C(5)) & std_logic'image(C(4)) & std_logic'image(C(3)) &
      std_logic'image(C(2)) & std_logic'image(C(1)) & std_logic'image(C(0));
    wait;
  end process;
end architecture A;
```

*EDIT*

As pointed out below, the `report` statements don't show the 'natural' order of these vectors, which was deliberate. You'll notice that this means that the literal value assigned to`A` is the reverse of the value shown by the report. If you don't like it, swap the indexing in the reports, or use `to_string` instead (2008-only).

Comment: C isn't 100111. Adding `report "C'left = " & integer'image(C'left) & " C'right = " & integer'image(C'right); report "to_string(C) = " & to_string(C); ` outputs `top.vhdl:33:5:@0ms:(report note): C'left = 0 C'right = 5` and `top.vhdl:35:5:@0ms:(report note): to_string(C) = 111001`.  Any continuous range of natural index values is acceptable, an **others** choice is not allowed and the left to right ordering is ascending (from the index type). Attributes of arrays values are derived from the elaborated object as is 'subtype. Named associations can be in any order, IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.7.1.

Comment: (Your A and B report statements are showing values in the wrong order, too.)

Comment: Que? The code is correct - I didn't say 'A is', but 'the code should show'. `to_string` has no choice other than to report an ascending range starting at index 0, because it has no other information. I've explicitly shown each bit starting at 5, downto 0, to avoid any confusion, and to make it obvious that the directions differ.

Comment: Your report says 'A is'. 6.4.1 *The value of a composite object is the aggregation of the values of its subelements*. More graciously your A, B and C reports don't show left to right order. An alias, e.g. `alias D: std_logic_vector(C'LENGTH - 1 downto 0) is C;` is used in math or conversion routines (e.g. to_string) to maintain left to right order regardless of ascending and descending ranges.  A similar D report statement would show left to right order: `(report note): D is '1''1''1''0''0''1'` should you use as here fixed order index element evaluation.

Comment: Indeed the report statement does say that, but thats' not normative... you have to read the text :) The reports don't have to show left-to-right order. The point was to explicitly show the value of each indexed bit; `to_string` doesn't do that, and relies on an understanding of the indexing, which was the whole point of the question. Maybe I should add something to the answer to make that more obvious? Or maybe I should just get on with what I'm paid for.